# Why the Button is put the Extra space between two button in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, layout

I Just created one `LinearLayout` with `WeightSum` and put Button inside it. but my `Button` is taking space without I apply any style or property is not work as i expected.

**xml code :**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#e6e6e6"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="13.0">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="T"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="A"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="J"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="R"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="D"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="K"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="I"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="E"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="F"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="G"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="H"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="L"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="C"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Output ScreenShot :**

[image]

Comment: Try and change the background of the button to a specific color, I guess the space will disappear. `android:background="#f00"` for all the buttons.

Comment: @SouravKanta Thanks it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of default background drawable.

Try setting custom drawable to button. e.g `android:background="#9e9e9e"`

You can also get custom drawable from [here](http://android-holo-colors.com/).

Answer (score 0):

set background of all Button to null

add below line to all button

android:background="@null"